# move a Composer package after an update to 'installer-paths'

Tags: composer-php

I installed a package with Composer, and one of that package's dependencies needs to be in a custom location. But of course I only read the README *after* installing.

So now, the package is in /vendor and it needs to be in, say, /special.

I've added the specification to my 'installer-paths' section, but `composer update` is not noticing that. I tried deleting the package files and doing `composer update` but that's no good either.

Is there a way of doing this without doing a `composer remove`, which is going to trigger a cascade of removals and unwanted updates?